# Multiple tables in one pandas dataframe split

Tags: python, pandas

I have loaded in a csv which looks like this

```
  Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 3
        Date      Price     Quantity     Colour
        2019        45         56         Blue
        2019        34         65         Red
        Date      Price     Quantity     Size
        2019        12         32         Large
        2019        45         11         Small
        Date      Price     Country     
        2019        12         UK        
        2019        45         US
```

I wanted to make this into a full dataframe, so the expected out put is this;

```
    Date      Price     Quantity     Colour  Size  Country
    2019        45         56         Blue   NaN    NaN    
    2019        34         65         Red    NaN    NaN    
    2019        12         32        NaN    Large   NaN    
    2019        45         11        NaN    Small   NaN    
    2019        12         32        NaN    NaN     UK
    2019        45         11        NaN    NaN     US
```

The word Date in the first column will always split the tables

Comment: how big is your csv? for this i would process in Python with regex and save as a new csv then read into pandas

Comment: funny thing, I am looking for a way to convert to the initial results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `Date` string is possible use for distinguish each group then compare and add [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), pass to `groupby` and in custom function create columns by first row and remove it by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
g = df.iloc[:, 0].eq('Date').cumsum()

def f(x):
    x.columns = x.iloc[0]
    return x.iloc[1:].dropna(how='all', axis=1)

df = df.groupby(g).apply(f).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   Date Price Quantity Colour   Size
0  2019    45       56   Blue    NaN
1  2019    34       65    Red    NaN
2  2019    12       32    NaN  Large
3  2019    45       11    NaN  Small
```

Comment: This is fantastic thanks so much. I'm getting an error on the last bit. I think its because the shapes don't match, which is my fault for giving a too basic example. I've changed the question slightly to highlight the issue. Is there a simple edit which would let this work?

Comment: ValueError: Plan shapes are not aligned

Comment: @fred.schwartz - I verify problem with some another data and working for solution

Comment: @fred.schwartz - Answer was edited. I think problem is with duplicated `NaN`s columns, can you check solution?

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`np.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) to use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
new_df = (pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(columns = group.iloc[0],
                                  index =group.index[1:],
                                  data = group.iloc[1:].values)
                    for i,group in df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//3)],sort = False)
            .dropna(how = 'all',axis = 1))
print(new_df)
   Date Price Quantity Colour   Size Country
1  2019    45       56   Blue    NaN     NaN
2  2019    34       65    Red    NaN     NaN
4  2019    12       32    NaN  Large     NaN
5  2019    45       11    NaN  Small     NaN
7  2019    12      NaN    NaN    NaN      UK
8  2019    45      NaN    NaN    NaN      US
```

---

If the length of each frame to concatenate is not the same then I would use [`Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html)

```
new_df = (pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(columns = group.iloc[0],
                                  index =group.index[1:],
                                  data = group.iloc[1:].values)
                    for i,group in df.groupby(df.iloc[:,0].eq('date').cumsum())],sort = False)
            .dropna(how = 'all',axis = 1))
print(new_df)
0  Date  Price  Quantity Colour
1  2019     45        56   Blue
2  2019     34        65    Red
3  Date  Price  Quantity   Size
4  2019     12        32  Large
5  2019     45        11  Small
6  Date  Price   Country    NaN
7  2019     12        UK    NaN
8  2019     45        US    NaN
```